# Clear TextField without controller in Flutter

Tags: flutter

My screen has multiple textfields, about 15 or so. I don't want to use TextEditingController due to performance reasons as the number of TextFields are likely to grow and I need to pass data from one widget to another back and forth. So I am using OnChanged method of the TextField and am setting a variable which will be used from the parent widget through a function. Now when I click on reset on the parent widget, how do I clear all the values in the TextField controls without using TextEditingController?

```
class Parent extends StatelessWidget {
    
    String txt='';
    myfunction(text)
    {
     txt=text;
    }
    
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
  ...
  Foo(myfunction);
  ....
  }
  }
  
  class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function myfunction;
  const Foo(this.myfunction);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (text) {
        myfunction( text);
      },...
      }
    }
```

Comment: and what is the problem with using a controller?

Comment: . My screen can have about 20 to 30 textfields, Having 30 controllers is not a good solution for performance reasons and memory issues. In future, I might add another 20 textfields too

Comment: having 30 or up to 50 textfiels is also not good and there's nothing wrong with controllers. I'll recommend you to use unique keys and a listview to make it performance.

Comment: 30 to 50 fields is bad??? A simple qr code generation for Contact can have 20 fields atleast, It all depends on the usecase

Answer (score 0):

You should try to declare all textfields with:

```
final TextEditingController name = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController age = TextEditingController();
```

Create one method like this :

```
resetAll() {
  name.clear();
  name.clear();
}
```

then you call **resetAll** on reset button like below:

```
onPressed:() => resetAll()
```

Comment: He mentioned without controller, isn't it?

Comment: I think it is not possible without TextEditingController

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but the text Fields will be reset if you dispose and reopen the screen holding the text Fields.